# tmap, always put biggest shapefiles as first layer

Tags: r, sf, tmap

I am using `TMAP` library to generate a series of maps. The number of maps to generate is huge and the number of shapefiles to plot in each map is also big.

Each shapefile is of a different size, some contain only one polygon, others several.

I am looking for a way to always plot the biggest shapefiles first (so that bigger shapefiles don't hide smaller ones). To illustrate this I generated a small image. The map to the left is bad because small shapefiles end up behind the bigger one. The one on the right is what I want to get.

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/t/u0SPKn6vZuySSp4l) to find the shapefiles I used in the example.

On the code below, what determines what shapefile is going to be plotted first depends on the alphabetical order of appearance in the "PAK" folder. Is there a way to sort the list based on polygon size? I was thinking I could generate a new df with in column 1 the name of each loaded shapefile, in column 2 the total size of the polygon(s) for each shapefile, sort that column and then generate a list from column 1.

```
# Load Packages
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(stringr)
library(tmap)
library(rlist)

`%!in%` <- Negate(`%in%`)

# Country 
ctry <- ("PAK")

for (c in ctry) {

# Set Directory
list <- list.files(paste0("~/Desktop/",c), ".shp$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=TRUE)

for (sf in list) {
  if(file.exists(paste0("~/Desktop/",c,"/",sf))) {
    files.sf <- st_read(paste0("~/Desktop/",c,"/",sf))
    assign(sf, files.sf)
  }
}

sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)

for (sf in list) {
  a <- get(sf)
  a$geometry <- a$geometry %>%
    s2::s2_rebuild() %>%
    sf::st_as_sfc()
}

data("World")
ctry<-subset(World, iso_a3==c)

global_ctry = tm_shape(ctry) + tm_polygons(alpha=0)

for (sp in list) {
  if(is(get(sp)$geometry,"sfc_POLYGON")) {
    global_ctry = global_ctry + tm_shape(get(sp)) + tm_polygons(col = "MAP_COLORS") + tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE)
  }
  else {
    NULL
  }
  
  if(is(get(sp)$geometry,"sfc_MULTIPOLYGON")) {
    global_ctry = global_ctry + tm_shape(get(sp)) + tm_polygons(col = "MAP_COLORS") + tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE)
  } 
  else {
    NULL
  }
}
  
tmap_save(global_ctry, paste0("~/Desktop/",c,"/map_global_ctry.pdf"))
```

[image]

Comment: What's stopping you from putting all the polygons in one spatial data frame and then ordering by area like you suggest? You can use `st_area` to get the area of a feature and then use `order` to rearrange the rows.

Comment: Indeed, great solution!